# how to retrieve deleted cloudant service on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

One of the cloudant service got deleted from our dashboard. And the cloudant service had historical data which we wanted to use for our project. Is there any way we can get all of it back?

Please help.

Comment: How was it deleted? I assume inside the Bluemix UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted your Cloudant service in Bluemix, it is deleted for good. I am not aware of any way to recover it. Possibly contact 
[Cloudant's Help Desk](https://cloudant.com/history/contact-us/) and see if they can recover it.

Hope this works!

**UPDATE**: I contacted Cloudant and they doubt it can be recovered but you can contact their engineers at support@cloudant.com ASAP.

Comment: We were able to get back all the DBs (thanks to Cloudant Support), but had to recreate the Service again.

Comment: Awesome to get your data back! Thought this would be a long shot.